# How can i get the text of a span element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Edited for tags and further explanation of the question

Hello ,i am fairly new to the web programming, sorry in advance if this sounds out of place.
My question is, i need to get customer's name and number  from this  `<span class="tag-element-content" title="${Customer No}">${Customer Name}-${Customer No}</span>` area, which is inside the code  below, any help would be very appreciated.

```
<div class="tagger" id="ChoosenCustomer">
                                        <div class="tags-container tag-view focused" id="branches">
                                            <div class="tag-element-container" dojoattachpoint="_tagsContainer">
                                                <div class="tag-decorated-element" name="ChoosenTags" id="" is-clicked="true">
                                                    <span class="tag-element-content" title="${Customer No}">${Customer Name}-${Customer No}</span>
                                                    <span id="RemoveCustomer" class="tag-element-delete icon-cross" search-id="" click=DeleteCustomer()></span>
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="" value="${Customer No}" is-clicked="true">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Sorry, question i typed first was kinda different, then i forgot to delete the tags, edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
let span_text = document.querySelector('.your-element-class').textContent;
```

with jQuery:

```
let span_text = $('.your-element-class').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use jquery on your project and :

```
var SpanText = $('.tag-element-content').text();
```

Comment: _"Use this code"_ - Why? How is a collection of `HTMLElement`s useful?

Answer (score 0):

in your case:

```
document.getElementById("anid").innerText;
```

and add the id to your element

Comment: _"and add the id to your element"_ - Why? There are ways that don't require to change the markup...